# Lion - override windows resizing restrictions for certain applications

Tags: macos, window-manager

I am a long time user of a windows manager tool in osx (SizeUp) that I love as it allows me to tile several different windows on my laptop screen while having a full editing window open on my secondary screen for coding.

I recently made the move up to OSX Lion and noticed that certain applications now seem to have restrictions on them for how they resize.  The applications that I have noticed are, unfortunately, 3 of the apps I normally have open while working:

- Skype
- iTunes
- Outlook

For all of these apps, when I resize them manually or using my windows manager tool, there seems to be a limit beneath which they won't go - i.e. they have limits set on their minimum height/width.  This means that I am unable to tile them effectively on my smaller screen.

I am wondering if there is a way of overriding these restrictions so that I am able to tell osx to ignore the settings globally (i.e. for all apps) or can I disable the restrictions on a per app basis?  Either solution would help.

Conversely, if there is another windows management tool that is able to universally override these restrictions, that would work as well,

Thanks.

Comment: I would ask SizeUp support, they would now for sure if they can go around this limitation. Also, try http://mizage.com/divvy/ if you haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hopeful that "moon" with it's custom resize window options would work, but if you set a custom window size lower than whatever iTunes doesn't want to go than, it ignores it and uses the iTunes minimum anyway.  It's looking like a "no"

Comment: Unfortunately I have come to that conclusion as well - yet another bullet point on the list of things I dislike about Lion