# Big Sur — disable windows-size shrinking limitations of windows with a minimum size restriction

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur, window-manager

This is a continuation of the question:

[Lion - override windows resizing restrictions for certain applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42153/lion-override-windows-resizing-restrictions-for-certain-applications)

on reducing the window size of applications that have a developer/manufacturer set minimum width or height you cannot shrink further below.

For example, iTunes, Signal, the Photos, Messages, Voice Memos, News etc. would only permit a width slightly greater than horizontal half of the 13 inch 2020 MacBook Air M1.

Imovies will not reduce width smaller than the full width of your screen, and only slightly reduce vertical size.

System Preferences will not resize at all — neither to expand or shrink on either axes — and these are just a few that are more of generic use.

I am hoping to find a setting (extremely unlikely), terminal code, or any other work around or solution requiring no disabling of the security system of Mac.

---

**Research**

I am a user of BetterSnapTool and BetterTouchTool neither of which allow it, and reviewed the suggested two applications suggested in the parent question, SizeUp and Divvy by Milage neither of which appear to have such a function.

Comment: I wish there was a solution to that, too, i use yabai to have tiling management on macOS, but it is very constrained when developers decided the app window had to take half the screen or more.